# Display ArrayList entries in multiline TextBox

Tags: c#, constructor, foreach, arraylist

I am having a problem with displaying a content from a ArrayList() stored as such:

```
private void btnEnter_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    public ArrayList books = new ArrayList();
    books = new ArrayList();

    // first I am just using lebels for easier input.
    books.Add(new Book(label1.Text, label2.Text, label3.Text, label4.Text, float.Parse(label5.Text)));
}
```

As we see I am using a constructor to store data with 5 elements. The problem is that I am not sure how to display the data using foreach loop:

```
public ArrayList books;
public BookList()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    foreach (string data in books)
        txtBookList.Text = data.ToString();
}
```

I am trying to display the content in multiline textbox and I am not sure what I'm exacly doing wrong. Any tips?

Here is the code for Book() constructor:

```
public Book(string title, string firstName, string lastName, string publisherName, float price)
: base(title, publisherName, price)
{
    this.authorFirstName = firstName;
    this.authorLastName = lastName;
}
```

-- EDIT --
One person pointed out that I do want to display the ArrayList as a objects. How would I do it?

Regards.

HelpNeeder

Comment: Yes it is. I am trying to display this in multiline TextBox.

Comment: Unless you're programming with .NET 1.1, you should never use `ArrayList`. If your list has items all of the same type, then you should use `List<itemType>`, for instance, `List<string>`.

Comment: The items are not the same type, the Price is in float. And I am asked to create an ArrayList.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a couple of problems here - the main one being that your ArrayList books isn't a collection of strings, it's a collection of book objects. Therefore your foreach loop needs to iterate through book objects instead of strings:

```
    foreach (Book b in books)
    {
        txtBookList.Text += b.authorFirstName;
        txtBookLIst.Text += b.authorLastName;
    }
```

The second problem is that you are trying to assign a string value to the txtBookList variable, which I'm assuming is a textbox. Try using the Text property instead and use the += operator to append new strings to the value, like above.

Comment: Well, the problem with this is that there is no arraylist in book. There I store only individual entries. I do want to pull the data from the array.

Comment: As someone pointed out answer that is same as your, I have to accept this as an answer. Thank you. The problem I had was that I didn't actually input anything and I had to make corrections to that before I started to output the arraylist entries.

Answer (score 1):

If this is for Windows Forms, take a look at the [TextBox.Lines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textboxbase.lines.aspx) property.  That should get you on the way to displaying multiple lines in the text box.